# How to Align Text on Xamarin Custom Picker

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2019, .net-5, picker

I have a Xamarin Forms project on Visual Studio 2019. I have a simple custom picker as I have not managed to do a custom one. Don't know how to even though I have searched it.

What I want is to align my text on the center and get rid of the cancel button. Is there a way to do this without a custom renderer?

Here is my Picker

```
 <Picker x:Name="CustomerPicker" Title="Seleccione un cliente"
                    SelectedIndexChanged="CustomerPicker_OnSelectedIndexChanged" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
```

I have used those properties but it still looks like this

[image]

Is there a way of doing this? If only with renderer, how? I can't find it properly explained. Please help and thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, the text alignment properties on `<Picker` only affect the one-line view (which shows any previously selected value). Changes to the full popup require custom renderers. On your earlier question about picker custom renderer, on the one answer there, I've added a link to an example that you might find useful. It doesn't show how to do what you want, but it looks like a good example for working with picker custom renderers. (OR perhaps someone will add a more specific answer here showing how to do what you want.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I have added another question as I already achieved making a custom renderer thanks to the link you provided but I don't know how to hide the cancel button without having to use a `NumberPicker`. Could you see if you can help?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the cancel button like below.

**Xaml:**

```
   <Picker x:Name="picker"
    Title="Select"
    TitleColor="Red">
        <Picker.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>item1</x:String>
                <x:String>item2</x:String>
                <x:String>item3</x:String>
                <x:String>item4</x:String>

            </x:Array>
        </Picker.ItemsSource>
    </Picker>
```

**Custom Renderer:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Picker), typeof(CustomPickerRenderer))]
namespace App1.Droid
{
public class CustomPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
{
    IElementController ElementController => Element as IElementController;
    public CustomPickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    private AlertDialog _dialog;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.NewElement == null || e.OldElement != null)
            return;

        Control.Click += Control_Click;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Control.Click -= Control_Click;
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void Control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Xamarin.Forms.Picker model = Element;

        var picker = new NumberPicker(Context);
        if (model.Items != null && model.Items.Any())
        {
            // set style here
            picker.MaxValue = model.Items.Count - 1;
            picker.MinValue = 0;
             
            picker.SetDisplayedValues(model.Items.ToArray());
            picker.WrapSelectorWheel = false;
            picker.Value = model.SelectedIndex;
        }

        var layout = new LinearLayout(Context) { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
        layout.AddView(picker);

        ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, true);

        var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context);
        builder.SetView(layout);

        builder.SetTitle(model.Title ?? "");
        //builder.SetNegativeButton("Cancel  ", (s, a) =>
        //{
        //    ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
        //    // It is possible for the Content of the Page to be changed when Focus is changed.
        //    // In this case, we'll lose our Control.
        //    Control?.ClearFocus();
        //    _dialog = null;
        //});
        builder.SetPositiveButton("Ok ", (s, a) =>
        {
            ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(Xamarin.Forms.Picker.SelectedIndexProperty, picker.Value);
            // It is possible for the Content of the Page to be changed on SelectedIndexChanged.
            // In this case, the Element & Control will no longer exist.
            if (Element != null)
            {
                if (model.Items.Count > 0 && Element.SelectedIndex >= 0)
                    Control.Text = model.Items[Element.SelectedIndex];
                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
                // It is also possible for the Content of the Page to be changed when Focus is changed.
                // In this case, we'll lose our Control.
                Control?.ClearFocus();
            }
            _dialog = null;
        });

        _dialog = builder.Create();
        _dialog.DismissEvent += (ssender, args) =>
        {
            ElementController?.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
        };
        _dialog.Show();
    }
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Any update? Have you solved this issue?